# OnClick Javascript Nothing Happens When Clicking Custom Button for Docusign In Salesforce

Tags: javascript, docusign

I've followed [this doc](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-for-salesforce-custom-button-logic.pdf) in order to create a custom button in Salesforce that attempts to send a DocuSign template to the contact (button placed on contact object). However, when the button is clicked, nothing happens. Could someone please provide some insight?

Code:

```
   {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//
var RC = '';
var RSL = '';
var RSRO = '';
var RROS = '';
var CCRM = '';
var CCTM = '';
var
    CCNM = '';
var CRCL = '';
var CRL = '';
var OCO = '';
var DST = '';
var LA = '';
var CEM = '';
var
    CES = '';
var STB = '';
var SSB = '';
var SES = '';
var SEM = '';
var SRS = '';
var SCS = '';
var
    RES = '';
//*************************************************//
// Modify individual options here:
// Related Content (default no related content)
RC = ''; //Ex: GetRelContentIDs("{!Opportunity.Id}");
// Recipient Signer Limit (default no limit)
RSL = ''; //Ex: '3'
// Recipient Starting Routing Order (default 1)
RSRO = ''; // Ex: '1'
// Recipient Routing Order Sequential (default not sequential)
RROS = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Custom Contact Role Map (default config role)
CCRM = ''; //Ex: 'Decision Maker~Signer1;Economic Buyer~Carbon Copy'
// Custom Contact Type Map (default Signer)
CCTM = ''; //Ex: 'Decision Maker~Signer;Economic Buyer~CC'
// Custom Contact Note Map (default no note)
CCNM = ''; //Ex: 'Decision Maker~Note for DM;Economic Buyer~Note For
EB;
DEFAULT_NOTE~Default Note '
    // Custom Related Contact List (default object contact)
CRCL = ''; //Ex:
'MyContacts__r,Email~Email__c;FirstName~First_Name__c;LastName~Last_Name__c;Role~Role__c, LoadDefaultContacts~0 '
    // Custom Recipient List
CRL = ''; //Ex:
'Email~;FirstName~;LastName~;Role~SignInPersonName~;RoutingOrder~;AccessCode~;Re
cipientNote~;
SignNow~, LoadDefaultContacts~1 '
    // One Click Option (default edit envelope screen)
OCO = ''; //Ex: Tag
// DocuSign Template ID (default no template)
DST = ''; //Ex: '67870A79-A0B5-4596-8AC1-CC7CC1EA01EB'
// Load Attachments (default on)
LA = ''; //Ex: '0'
// Custom Email Message (default in config)
CEM = ''; //Ex: 'Envelope sent by [FirstName] [LastName] ([Email])!'
// Custom Email Subject (default in config)
CES = ''; //Ex: 'Re: Opportunity Name: {!Opportunity.Name}'
// Show Tag Button (default in config)
STB = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Show Send Button (default in config)
SSB = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Show Email Subject (default in config)
SES = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Show Email Message (default in config)
SEM = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Show Reminder/Expire (default in config)
SRS = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Show Chatter (default in config)
SCS = ''; //Ex: '1'
// Reminder and Expiration Settings
RES = ''; //Ex: '0,1,2,0,120,3'
//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********//
window.location.href =
    "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC=" + RC + "&RSL=" + RSL + "&RSRO=" + RSRO + "&RROS=" + RROS + "&CCRM=" + CCRM + "&CCTM=" + CCTM + "&CRCL=" + CRC
L + "&CRL=" + CRL + "&OCO=" + OCO + "&DST=" + DST + "&CCNM=" + CCNM + "&LA=" + LA + "&CEM=" + CEM + "&CES=
"+CES+" & SRS = "+SRS+" & STB = "+STB+" & SSB = "+SSB+" & SES = "+SES+" & SEM = "+SEM+" & SRS = "+SRS+" &
    SCS = "+SCS+" & RES = "+RES;
    //*******************************************//
```

Comment: Is it not sending email from your Sandbox org?

Comment: If there are no line breaks in your JavaScript as you've pasted here, that'll be a problem due to the liberal usage of `//` comment line sequences within it - notably the first two characters of this single line of code. On first glance, the reason it isn't working is because you've got a single line of code which starts with `//` commenting it out.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkPond The instructions said to remove the hard returns so that is what I was attempting to do. I take it there should be line breaks then?

Comment: When I use the code with line breaks that manjit_singh edited above I get A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

Unexpected token ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")} 

var conObj = new sforce.SObject("Contact"); 
conObj.Id = '{!Contact.Id}'; 
conObj.RecordTypeId = '01270000000N0Nh'; 
var result = sforce.connection.update([conObj]); 

if (result[0].success=='false') { 
alert(result[0].errors.message); 
} else { 
location.reload(true); 
} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var 
CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var 
CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var 
RES=''; 
CCRM = '8~Referrer'; 
OCO = 'Send'; //Ex: Tag 
DST = '1921E139-7CCD-4022-986A-B21B8E7FB29C'; //Ex: '67870A79-A0B5-4596-8AC1-CC7CC1EA01EB' 
window.location.href = 
"/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Contact.Id}&RC="+RC+ 
"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
```

The above is the code I used to ultimately accomplish this. The first block changes the contact record type, the second sends the DocuSign template.